# How to update Chromium on RPi 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+, chromium, troubleshooting

I'm brand new to Pi, and I found that the Raspberry Pi chromium is not as updated as standard Chromium. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
For clarification, I am on Raspbian 2.5 (Nov. 2018) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. What  I'm referring to as "standard" chromium would be (currently) Chromium 71, basically an un-googlified Chrome 71. However, if I try to do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, it says that version 65 is up to date. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong that can be fixed or if Chromium 65 is the most recent for Pi. Many of the answers on the site are outdated (for Jessie) and don't work. I have not gotten any errors, just "chromium-browser is up to date".

Comment: Do you use Raspbian? What is *standard* Chromium? Does Chromium 65 isn't Standard on Raspbian? What does all answers you tried stated to archive? Updating to Standard Chromium 65? What error messages you get if any?

Comment: Just added clarification. If you check your Chromium and it is version 65, then I am up to date. I am just making sure that I'm not behind.

Answer (score 2):

Another user asked the same question 7 hours later. I seems nobody notices your question. You can find an accepted answer to the other question at [Is it possible to upgrade Chromium past v65?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92303/79866). Also have a look at the interesting comments there to this issue.