# Is it possible to upgrade Chromium past v65?

Tags: chromium, terminal, selenium

I'm trying to use chromedriver for a python program and the latest version requires v70-72. My current version of chromium on raspberry pi is 65.0.3325.181 that was after upgrading and updating my raspberry pi. I read somewhere that chromium v66 and above isn't supported on raspberry pi. Is that true or am I upgrading it wrong? I'm on raspberry pi 3, I have run

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in terminal so far. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the Debian world; Debian is a very conservative OS and NEVER has the latest versions. If you **REALLY** need the latest (which is doubtful) you will need to build it from source.

Comment: Your question is duplicate of [How to update Chromium on RPi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/92287/79866).

Comment: @Milliways "NEVER" That's just wrong, some packages are kept close to latest, Chromium is one of them, it's just the Raspberry Pi repo needs ARM code and that's not maintained as well. Latest stable Chrome is 71, same one the Chromium debian repo has https://packages.debian.org/stretch/chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can remember, arm support for chromium has been dropped since version 65. So, even by building from sources, you won't be able to used it on your rpi.

Please someone prove me I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah I read that from somewhere else, this confirms it.

Comment: @FuturePythonWizard someone's memory without evidence confirms nothing. Simon Long says: 16th Nov 2018
"We update Chromium every few months, but the person who hacks it to include the hardware acceleration has been busy doing just that for VLC for the last few months instead! He’ll be back on Chromium again soon, so yes, there will be a new version at some point in the next few months." Even when this happens it is unlikely to be the "latest" - just the version Debian supports.

Comment: Ok thanks, I managed to get my program to work without the latest version of chromium anyways!

Comment: @Milliways I believe you but who is Simon Long? What is the evidence of your comment?

Comment: On the raspberry pi forums, specifically at this link,  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=225632, a user said, "Due to various changes to Chromium Browser the RPF can only offer chromium-browser version 65 at present, personally would not expect any update this side of Christmas." That was on October 27th 2018.

Answer (score 4):

Available as a snap package :

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
sudo snap install chromium 
snap run chromium
```

However it seems to be rather unstable, and does not appear on the raspberry pi menu system. Complains about missing symbols on startup, and sometimes about the namespace of the mounted snap folder. Snap packages are put together by Canonical and not by Debian or the Raspberry Pi foundation. Typing this in Chromium 71.0.3578.98 on a PI 3.

```
Chromium snap info - https://uappexplorer.com/snap/ubuntu/chromium
Intro to snaps - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#0
```

Most snaps are exclusive to AMD64 architectures, however the Chromium snap will run on Intel32 and armhf (Raspberry PI CPU)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ snap list
Name               Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
chromium           71.0.3578.98    569   stable    canonical✓  -
core               16-2.37         6260  stable    canonical✓  core
core18             18              596   stable    canonical✓  base
gtk-common-themes  0.1-4-g88bc1b2  818   stable    canonical✓  -
hello-world        6.3             27    stable    canonical✓  devmode
```